# What "Bad Thing" happened on the Joel on Software off topic forums?

Tags: discussion, blog

In [stack exchange podcast #30](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/se-podcast-30-robert-cartaino-rebecca-chernoff/) Joel is talking about his Usenet group; How it was built and evolved he then goes on to talk about them adding and "off topic" this is going at about the 8 minutes mark but "he won't go into it".

Does anyone know what happened?!

Comment: The horror! The unmentionable horror!!

Comment: Caching... it's always caching... oh...wait...

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BuildingCommunitieswithSo.html (search for "off topic")

Comment: @yannis reminds me of this http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/meta-is-murder.html

Answer (score 19):

Joel doesn't like to talk about it. It still scares him too much. But after a dozen Ice Teas from Long Island, he finally told me what happened. He said

> Once upon a time in a magical kingdom lived a unicorn. He was magical in a magical kingdom.
>   And he was a kingdom in a magical unicorn. But then something horrendous happened. The unicorn started to squeal and moan. And from his mouth I could hear the devil speak …

Obviously, the magical kingdom was the Usenet. And the Unicorn was its users. It's a metaphor (which is why Meta is called Meta by the way). And that's it. True Story. They even made a [music video out of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yYZa-70u_M)

Comment: It had to have something with unicorns

Comment: **HAPPY HAPPY HAPPY HAPPY, DEATH.**

Comment: I am trying to wrap my brain around that video... did I see a nazi unicorn?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII well, did you or did you nazi a unicorn?

Comment: Wanna C tru evil? => [this](http://mcphee.com/shop/inflatable-evil-unicorn-horn-for-cats.html)

Comment: ... I got nothin'.

Comment: You sir, win the internets...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn have you tried [this](http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_liddyjqIfV1qf4060o1_500.png)